# Ionic: iOS text cursor not showing up when tapped input or textarea

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am having this issue in ionic application. The issue exist in **iOS device** only

The issue:
Whenever I tap on `ion-input` or simply `input` textbox or textarea, the keyboard opens, this is fine, but the text cursor doesn't show up in the inputs. I have to tap again to show text cursor.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue??

My ionic and angular details

```
Ionic Framework: 3.8.0
Ionic App Scripts: 3.0.1
Angular Core: 4.4.4
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.4.4
Node: 6.10.3
```

Comment: We're having the same issue, have you had any luck?

Comment: same problem. no idea how to fix this. did you have any luck? thanks

Comment: you should write some of your design code so people can understand.

Comment: I got the same issue, and resolved it. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using ion-item as a wrapper of ion-input worked for me.

for example,

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" class="input-fields" [(ngModel)]="loginCredentials.username" placeholder="Username"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
<ion-list>
```